# Angular - Control the visibility text inside input box when it's disabled state is toggled

Tags: angular

I have an input form control, which might have or might not have any text inside it. I have another dropdown form control, when I change the dropdown value to a specific value, only then I am enabling the input box, if anything else is selected in the dropdown, the input will be disabled. Below is the code

```
    formGroup.get('dataType').valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue  => {
      if(selectedValue.toLowerCase() !== 'value list') {
          formGroup.get('inputValues').disable();
        } else {
          formGroup.get('inputValues').enable();
        }
    });
```

So, the inputValues field might have something when it is enabled, and when we disable the field by selecting dropdown box, the field is getting disabled but the text inside still is visible. Is there a way that I can control this state/visibility?

For example, let say the textbox holds a value "Vehicle Registered" when it is enabled, and when it is disabled, the value should be cleared, and when again when we enable, value should display again.

[image]

As we can see in the first row, the field got disabled but still visible. Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can probably store the value of `formGroup.get('inputValues')` and before disabling it, just set it to empty, and when you enable it, set the formControl value back by using the cached value.

```
let cachedInputVal = '';
formGroup.get('dataType').valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue  => {
      if(selectedValue.toLowerCase() !== 'value list') {
          cachedInputVal = formGroup.get('inputValues').value;
          formGroup.get('inputValues').patchValue('');
          formGroup.get('inputValues').disable();
        } else {
          formGroup.get('inputValues').patchValue(cachedInputVal);
          formGroup.get('inputValues').enable();
          cachedInputVal = '';
        }
    });
```

Comment: this code partially works. I have 3 dropdown values say DATE, STRING, Value List. It works when change from DATE to Value List or STRING to Value List vice versa. But when I change DATE to STRING and then Value List, the value is becoming empty

Comment: I think it has to do with the `if/else` condition, where we are checking for `selectedValue`. For simplicity, you can remove the `cachedInputVal = ''` in the `else` block.